# sort the file contents in ascending and descending order

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I want to sort the below log file based on increasing timestamp and decreasing severity.Below is my Input.txt and I want to write the output in another file.Attached my Java code.Pls suggest to fix this

```
[2015-11-19 10:33:54.934+0000] [HOST1] [INFO] [CLASS1] [MESSAGE1 something] 
[2015-11-19 10:31:55.128+0000] [HOST2] [ERROR] [CLASS2] [MESSAGE2 random] 
[2015-11-19 10:31:55.128+0000] [HOST3] [INFO] [CLASS6] [MESSAGE5 from another host] 
[2015-11-19 10:37:55.246+0000] [HOST2] [WARN] [CLASS9] [MESSAGE9 again]
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SortLogFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Input.txt"));
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Output.txt"));
            String file;
            while ((file = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                rows.add(file);
            }
            Collections.sort(rows);
            String[] strArr = rows.toArray(new String[0]);
            for (String cur : strArr)
                outputStream.println(cur);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please, format you code..

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to represent each line. This class must have two attributes (date and severity).
For the severity one, it's better to use an enum with a value, so it can be compared.
Add all objects to a list and sort it.

```
list.sort((a, b) -> {
    if (a.getData().equals(b.getData())) {
        return a.getSeverity().compareTo(b.getSeverity);
    } else {
        return a.getData().compareTo(b.getData());

    }
});
```